# How do I integrate MongoDB and Hazelcast without mentioning a specific schema?

Tags: mongodb, hazelcast

I am aware of how we create POJO classes (Java) and map them to the schema of the data in MongoDB, and create a connection with spring data. But if I don't have a specific schema and I want to have MongoDB as a back end for my cache in Hazelcast, how do I do that? In my use-case specifically, I have a cache which needs to keep mongodb updated with whatever updates it comes across.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/mongodb

Do note that this is a sample code that is meant for referential purposes only, do not copy paste into your production system.

Comment: But this is also for documents with a fixed schema. The Supplement class defines it. Is it not possible to do this without fixing a schema?

Comment: You can do anything that you like in MapStore, for that would be your own implementation - schema or no schema. Hazelcast does not provide any implementation of MapStore/Loader for any type of database/datastore.

Comment: Yes, but I will be creating a map using an object of a class, which will define he schema, right? Just like the Supplement class here in your example.

Comment: `supplements.set("1", new Supplement("bcaa", 10));`
`supplements.set("2", new Supplement("protein", 100));`
`supplements.set("3", new Supplement("glucosamine", 200));`

@wildnez

Comment: Supplements is a map and Supplement is the value in that map. You can build a value any which way you like as its just a Java object.